Find number of days in between dates of observations belonging to the same group in R
I have a dataset with
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                 type=c('type1','type2','type1','type1','type2', 'type3'),
                 date=c('01/01/2014','01/06/2015','01/06/2015','07/04/2017','05/10/2018', '05/01/2026'))

I would like to compute the number of days in between dates of IDs belonging to the same group
The result would look like the values in the variable days_in_between in the following dataframe
data.frame(ID=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
          type=c('type1','type1','type1','type2', 'type2','type3'),
          date=c('01/01/2014','01/06/2015','07/04/2017', '01/06/2017','05/10/2018', '05/01/2026'),
          days_in_between = c(NA, 370, 910, NA, 489, NA))

I have tried this which works
df%>%group_by(type)%>%mutate(diff=date-lag(date))

but it is a bit slow as I have a very big dataset. Just wondering if there is a quicker option?

To sort dates, it will be easier to put them into Date format, which in R is always displayed as YYYY-MM-DD. (You can always output as other formats, but they won't be Date data anymore...)
Then you can sort by date (and optionally by type, if you want to make sure those are output in order), and calculate the difference by type between each value and the preceding (lag) value.
df |>
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) |>
  arrange(type, date) |>
  mutate(days_in_between = date - lag(date), .by = type)

Result (using the provided sample data, which varies from the provided output)
  ID  type       date days_in_between
1  1 type1 2014-01-01         NA days
2  3 type1 2015-01-06        370 days
3  4 type1 2017-07-04        910 days
4  2 type2 2015-01-06         NA days
5  5 type2 2018-05-10       1220 days
6  6 type3 2026-05-01         NA days

If you have like tens of thousands of groups (or more), it may be worthwhile shunting the calculations to data.table or duckplyr, which you can do in one step using either of the lines below. They will translate most dplyr pipes into either of those packages, which are much faster if you have many groups to calculate in.
df |>
  dtplyr::lazy_dt() |>
  ... (the rest)

or
df |>
  duckplyr::as_duckplyr_df() |>
  ... (the rest)

When I ran the dplyr code on this sample data with one million rows and 10k types, it took 77 seconds, but only about 1 second with either the dtplyr or duckplyr conversions.
set.seed(42)
data.frame(type = sample(1:10000, 1E6, TRUE),
           date = ymd(20000101) + sample(1:10000, 1E6, TRUE)) -> df


I recommend {collapse}. A lengthy syntax which mimics {dplyr}:
library(collapse)
system.time({
  df0 |>
    roworder(type, date) |>
    fgroup_by(type) |>
    fmutate(diff =  date - flag(date))
})

on a four year old M1 chip with 16 GB of RAM:
   user  system elapsed 
  0.049   0.006   0.055 


Note.
Data taken from @JonSpring's answer, but named df0:
set.seed(111124)
df0 = data.frame(type = sample(1:10000, 1E6, TRUE),
                 date = lubridate::ymd(20000101) + sample(1:10000, 1E6, TRUE)) 


I would split them into separate data frames first, this could allow parallel processing if you wanted to speed up the processing time of the operation.
Hope this answers the question!
df1 <- df %>%
  filter(type == 'type1') %>%
  mutate(diff = date - lag(date))

df2 <- df %>%
  filter(type == 'type2') %>%
  mutate(diff = date - lag(date))

df3 <- df %>%
  filter(type == 'type3') %>%
  mutate(diff = date - lag(date))

combined_df <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3)


Without further work it does allow parallel processing. If you recommend such an approach, then please show. The answer as given cannot be generalised.

with base R, you can try
transform(
  sort_by(df, ~ type + date),
  days_in_between = ave(
    as.integer(as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y")),
    type,
    FUN = \(x) c(NA, diff(x))
  )
)

which gives
  ID  type       date days_in_between
1  1 type1 01/01/2014              NA
3  3 type1 01/06/2015             370
4  4 type1 07/04/2017             910
2  2 type2 01/06/2015              NA
5  5 type2 05/10/2018            1220
6  6 type3 05/01/2026              NA

